# indexing question

Tags: mysql

I have a table w/ 3 columns: name, phone, date. 
I have 3 indexes: 1 on phone, 1 on date and 1 on phone and date. 
I have the following statement:

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC) as t GROUP BY phone

Basically, I want to get all unique phone numbers ordered by date. This table has about 2.5 million rows but takes forever to execute....are my indexes right?

UPDATE:

My EXPLAIN statement comes back with 2 rows: 1 for primary table and 1 for derived table.

It says I am using temporary and using filesort for my primary table.

For my derived table, it says my possible keys are (phone), and (phone, date) but it is using filesort.

Comment: try addind 'explain' at the beginning and look for big numbers or table scans: explain SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC) as t GROUP BY phone

Comment: What other columns do you have that * is selecting?  
Which of those columns do you need in the final result?  The subquery's `order by` is expensive and its effect is discarded.

Comment: Unique phone numbers ordered by date, do you want max(date) or min(date) for a phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your 3rd index is redundant, since it should already be covered by the individual indexes on the date and phone columns.

However, in your case I don't think the indexes are the real cause of the query being slow. Instead the real problem is probably the inner query that is producing huge temporary data set and as far as I know MySql is not really optimized for this.

UPDATE:
I think the following query should have the same output as yours, but would avoid the inner select:

```
SELECT phone, max(date) as maxDate 
FROM people 
WHERE phone IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY phone
ORDER BY maxDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not need the extra select * from

```
SELECT distinct phone
FROM people 
WHERE phone IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY phone, date DESC
```

UPDATE - for all th ecolumns try this:

```
SELECT name, date, distinct phone     
FROM people 
WHERE phone IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY phone, date DESC
```

Comment: that won't return all the columns

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index `(phone, date)` an index of `(phone)` is not needed as MySQL can easily use the first index for that.

Depending on the amount of `NULL` `phone`numbers the indexes are irrelevant. You first ask the database server to get all elemenmts with phone number, if the majority has a phone number it won't care about the index then sort all of that by date, than sort again by phone and aggregate, so assuming most of your entries have a phone number you are sorting two  times.

You can easily write this in a single query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone IS NOT NULL GROUP BY phone, date DESC
```

See also the output of

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone IS NOT NULL ORDER BY date DESC) as t GROUP BY phone
```

vs.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone IS NOT NULL GROUP BY phone, date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be the "is not null" clause.  Using this clause causes the db to miss the index.  It has to do a full table scan to check the condition.  Consider using a different default value to represent null so you can hit your index.